# how to call a namespace function from within a .ASM file?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, namespaces, x86-64

I suppose my first question should be whether it's actually possible to do this ? AND secondly what would be the syntax in calling the namespaced function from my .ASM file ?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
======= Test.h =======

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    void PrintString()
    {
         // do something here
    }
}

==== Test.asm ===

EXTERN PrintString:PROC

.data    

    dbgString byte "Just a string!", 0

.code

main PROC

    CALL PrintString    ;gives linking error
main ENDP

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol PrintString referenced in function main
```

Comment: With “namespace function,” do you mean a function in a C++ name space?  If yes, why is this tagged “C” and not “C++?”

Comment: Anyway, this boils down to C++ linkage vs C linkage.  To call functions with C++ linkage, you need to find the appropriate symbol name by applying the correct *name mangling.*  That in turn depends on the ABI you are programming for.  Please specify which ABI (operating system and architecture) you are programming for.

Comment: @fuz. My namespace is located within a .h file but I'm not how to answer the very first question you asked. I'm writing for Windows 8.1 and using a x86-64 architecture. Does this help ? Thanks.

Comment: It helps!  C does not have name spaces, only C++ has.  Are you programming in C++?  Or is this some other language?

Comment: Compile a C++ function that calls your function, and look at the compiler's asm output for it.  (e.g. on https://godbolt.org/).  That will sort out the name mangling for you, if you don't want to declare the function as `extern "C"`.

Comment: @fuz thanks Yes I'm programming in C++.

Comment: Namespace only contributes to the name mangling. Use the mangled name.